# Pagination with one-to-many relationship (Hibernate/Spring/Oracle)

Tags: oracle, spring, hibernate, one-to-many

I need to implement pagination that is consistent and efficient for a list of objects that have a one-to-many relationship.  Items in the list are displayed in groups, and the number of group members varies among groups.  Some groups may not contain any members. The paging should be determined by the number of group members.

For example, think about a family photo directory. Here are the rules:

1. Each family unit is grouped together as a set on the page.
2. Any number of families can appear on the same page.
3. There should be approximately 10 photos per page.
4. The whole family must appear on the same page.  If the last family on the page will overflow the 10 picture limit, either keep that family on this page OR display them on the next page, and do this consistently.
5. If there are no photos of the family members, the family grouping will appear without any pictures.  Since there are no pictures, this group will not count towards the 10 picture limit.
6. It is possible to have a family with more than 10 photos, and this case should be handled.

Please share any tips for developing this algorithm.  I would greatly appreciate any platform-specific hints as well. The application uses Hibernate 3.3.2 and Spring 2.5.6.  The database is Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 1):

In Hibernate you can limit the number of rows returned by a query, i. e. set the page size, with

```
Query.setMaxResults(nbr);
```

When you want to load a different page then the first page, then you set the first row of the page with

```
query.setFirstResult(rowNr);
```

Both only has effect to the main table (familiy), but it does not limit the number of rows in the child table (photos). And then you have very special demands (if the first family has three photos, then the second family only is allowed seven photos on that page, not ten as usual). For this I recommend to to forget the Hibernate one-to-many relation in family and you do it manually. This gives you full control about loading the photos and limit their number.

- In family you do *not* include the hibernate property for photos.
- Instead you write a method 'getPhotos(int nbr_of_photos)' in the class family where you manually load the photos for this family from the photo table (using Session and Query). You can limit their number as you need. You can cache the result in the family object if convenient (optional, not necessary).
- In photo you can define the id of the family as a simple numeric or string property, or you can define a many-to-ony property to family.